# Sub query not connected with main query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Below query is used to retrieve records from database to shown in report. But the SENOKO AND EUNOS column show duplicate total in every row. This seems the subquery did not connected to the main query causes the filtering is not taken.

```
SELECT whbal.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, 
   (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
    FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='SKW') AS SENOKO
   (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight) / 1000)) 
    FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='EKW') AS EUNOS
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON whbal.customer=customer.customer AND whbal.date_create<=@date1                   
INNER JOIN stktype ON whbal.stock_type=stktype.stock_type
WHERE whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2 AND whbal.stock_type=@type
GROUP BY whbal.customer, customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level
```

Result:

[image]

Do anyone know what is the problem and solution, please advise and guide.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
SELECT whbal.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse='SKW' 
        THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) 
           + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack) 
         * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight)
        ELSE 0.0 END
       / 1000.0) AS SENOKO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse='EKW' 
        THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_good) 
           + CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.qty_slack) 
         * CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 3), whbal.std_weight)
        ELSE 0.0 END
       / 1000.0) AS EUNOS
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON whbal.customer=customer.customer AND whbal.date_create<=@date1                   
INNER JOIN stktype ON whbal.stock_type=stktype.stock_type
WHERE whbal.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2 AND whbal.stock_type=@type
GROUP BY whbal.customer, customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level
```